# Flutter preload Google Maps widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Cupertino Tabbar where one page (the third page) has a Google maps widget.

The app starts on page one. 
But is it possible to meanwhile load the Maps widget? (So if page 3 is selected Google Maps is already loaded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using IndexedStack with Tabbar, pages will be preloaded all at a time, [Tabbar with IndexedStack](https://medium.com/fluttervn/making-bottom-tabbar-with-flutter-5ff82e8defe0)